# What effect would using different types of orders have on a binary search tree?

Tags: ds.data-structures, partial-order, order-theory

Recently, I was coding a comparator function for use in a set backed by a binary search tree, and the set kept saying that it didn't contain elements that I had previously added to it. I eventually realized that the ordering I had implemented in the comparator was to blame, which got me thinking:

How would a binary search tree change if its elements were ordered by different orders (partial, total, strict, etc...)?

[Documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#Containers) on the [C++ STL set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) says that the ordering must be strict and weak otherwise behavior is 'undefined', but I'd be interested to hear if anyone could give a more in-depth analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for, but what happens if you insert an element from a partial order that isn't comparable to the root. What do you do then ?

Comment: related?: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/binary-search-generalizations-for-posets/8943#8943

Comment: There are specialised data-structures for different order types... albeit BSTs don't fit into this category.